# How do I layout list items to behave like a table rows?

Tags: android

I do not want to use `TableLayout` because my data model and UI perfectly fit into `ListView`. But I need to have fields in list items to organize in columns through hole `ListView`. I want to use two-line list item model with about 4-5 columns in a second line. I do know how to make custom layouts and custom array adapters for `ListView`. The question is about positioning `TextView`'s in a list item custom layout so that they become nicely aligned. Surely I can not use absolute widths because there are so many screen sizes, but I can not think of any other option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wrap your `TextViews` in a `LinearLayout` then you can use the `layout_weight` attribute:

```
 <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="25">
    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="25">
    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="25">
    <TextView android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="25">
  <LinearLayout>
```

This will make your `TextView` occupy 25% of the available width and should keep them vertical aligned(you could also set the gravity for the `TexView` to left). The above code is an example for 4 `TextViews`, if you have more or less you must adapt the `layout_weight` attribute so that the sum of all the `layout_weight` attributes is 100.
I hope this is what you want.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the best compromise, I will test an see.